# Unable to install update-alternatives package

Tags: apt, update-alternatives

I am setting up my new Ubuntu 15.10 VM. I need to install `update-alternatives` on it. I ran the command `sudo apt-get install update-alternatives`, however, I get the following output in the terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package update-alternatives
```

I can install all other packages I've wanted till now, except`update-alternatives`. Is this a repo issue? Do I need to add a repo name in the sources? Any suggestions on this will be really helpful.

Comment: `/usr/bin/update-alternatives` is provided by the package `dpkg`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have `update-alternatives`; there is nothing to install. Run `which update-alternatives` to check where it is on your `$PATH`.

Comment: Yes! got it. It was in /usr/sbin. Thanks!

Comment: @Knud Larsen.......Thanks for your pointers too

Comment: I need to confirm one point. "A fresh Ubuntu setup by default has the "update-alternatives" package and there is no need to install it explicitly". Am I right ?

Comment: dpkg is always installed. Else no package handling. http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily-updates/amd64/dpkg/filelist

Comment: ok. Thanks, Knud Larsen. That was really helpful!